# API JSON-response to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I would prefer to have this output in another format but I am struggling with how to get it.

CODE:

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api-extern.XXX.se')
    conn.request("GET", "/product/v1/product?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_data)
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\aaa.bbb\Documents\Python Scripts\file.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
    conn.close()
```

OUTPUT
all products for a site are merged to one cell
[image: output from the code]

WANTED OUTPUT
Either:

- all products in a row and all sites as columns
- or all flat with first site 1 with all products as rows and then site 2 with all products.

Expected output alternative 1

[image: wanted output alternative 1]

Expected output alternative 2

[image: wanted output alternative 2]

The structure of the output is:
[

```
  {
    "SiteId": "string",
    "Products": [
      {
        "ProductId": "string",
        "ProductNumber": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Example

```
[{
    "SiteId": "0102",
    "Products": [{
        "ProductId": "12107708",
        "ProductNumber": "7070501"
      },
      {
        "ProductId": "15578",
        "ProductNumber": "26804"
      },
      {
        "ProductId": "15671",
        "ProductNumber": "600102"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output from `pprint(data)` in Spyder is:

```
{'ProductId': '21831062', 'ProductNumber': '3364603'},
{'ProductId': '24432865', 'ProductNumber': '133101'},
{'ProductId': '24432978', 'ProductNumber': '1194515'},
{'ProductId': '1029420', 'ProductNumber': '198301'},
{'ProductId': '12282', 'ProductNumber': '408701'},
{'ProductId': '12946229', 'ProductNumber': '7174706'},
{'ProductId': '13278', 'ProductNumber': '42302'},
{'ProductId': '1028718', 'ProductNumber': '7536001'},
{'ProductId': '12945249', 'ProductNumber': '197404'},
{'ProductId': '16380', 'ProductNumber': '1133301'},
{'ProductId': '1866', 'ProductNumber': '257102'},
{'ProductId': '24420534', 'ProductNumber': '3422315'},
{'ProductId': '24424403', 'ProductNumber': '259301'},
{'ProductId': '10276', 'ProductNumber': '18004'},
{'ProductId': '1158212', 'ProductNumber': '689401'},
{'ProductId': '21775', 'ProductNumber': '395806'},
```

Comment: Can you share the raw response that you're getting so we can see what is happening?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you mean with raw response or how to show you this (not experienced with python or Spyder). But if I add print(data) to my code, the response in Spyder is:

Comment: You can use the [edit] button below the question to make improvements to your question. Copy / paste the output from your `print(data)` there, and format it is as code so we can help better.

Comment: For some reason i can't edit my comment anymore. The output is very large so it give you a piece here: {"ProductId":"25077","ProductNumber":"694202"},{"ProductId":"369","ProductNumber":"44802"},{"ProductId":"358700","ProductNumber":"555201"},{"ProductId":"1084111","ProductNumber":"463801"}

Comment: Where does `SiteId` come from? It does not appear to be in your output of `data`

Comment: it is, but the output is so large so when I try to copy from the output window in Spyder i can't see the top of the output. It cuts the output it shows. But i figured out the structure based on the specification of the API, see updated question.

Comment: @Patric, please paste the output to Pastebin (https://pastebin.com/) and share the link.

Comment: And with the output you mean the print(data) or the csv? Since I don't know how to copy the entire print(data) output. But i assume the example in the questions would be enough for answering the questions since it describes the structure well, or?

Comment: The print data, which is the raw output.

Comment: @Patric, just realized you were calling a Pandas method. I will not be able to help with that, so please ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first output with multiple site columns could be achieved just using the built in CSV module. To do this you need to first parse the whole file to determine all the required sites for the heading. Whilst doing this create a list of sites with given `ProductId` and `ProductNumber` combinations:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv


# Sample data
json_data = [
    {"SiteId" : "0102", "Products" : [{"ProductId" : "12107708", "ProductNumber" : "7070501"}, {"ProductId" : "15578", "ProductNumber" : "26804"}, {"ProductId" : "15671", "ProductNumber" : "600102"}]}, 
    {"SiteId" : "0104", "Products" : [{"ProductId" : "12107708", "ProductNumber" : "7070501"}, {"ProductId" : "15579", "ProductNumber" : "26804"}, {"ProductId" : "15671", "ProductNumber" : "600102"}]}
]

data = defaultdict(list)
sites = set()

for site in json_data:
    for product in site['Products']:
        site_text = f"site {site['SiteId']}"
        data[(product['ProductId'], product['ProductNumber'])].append(site_text)
        sites.add(site_text)

fieldnames = ['ProductId', 'ProductNumber', *sorted(sites)]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for (id, number) in data:
        row = {'ProductId' : id, 'ProductNumber' : number}

        for site in data[(id, number)]:
            row[site] = 1

        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

So for the sample data given (with two sites), you would get the following `output.csv` output:

```
ProductId,ProductNumber,site 0102,site 0104
12107708,7070501,1,1
15578,26804,1,
15671,600102,1,1
15579,26804,,1
```

Comment: Great! Will try it later today and get back to you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect!!